# Installing rclone according to the official instructions but permission denied

Tags: linux, terminal, permissions, sudo, rclone

Noob question, but hear me out

So I installed rclone word-for-word according to this (https://rclone.org/install/)

However, when I got around to `rclone config` the terminal returned `2020/02/28 11:37:29 Failed to load config file "/home/myUser/.config/rclone/rclone.conf": open /home/myUser/.config/rclone/rclone.conf: permission denied`

In an attempt to fix this I ran `chmod u+x "/home/myUser/.config/rclone/rclone.conf"` which returned `chmod: changing permissions of '/home/myUser/.config/rclone/rclone.conf': Operation not permitted`

Then I ran the same command prefixed with `sudo` which seemed to work. Yet after running `rclone config` again the same permission denied error appeared. What should I do? What did I do incorrectly during install? I just want to be able to run `rclone config` without having to use `sudo`.

Unrelated side note I had a similar experience with Anaconda in which I can't run the command for opening the program without `sudo` but as I ran the command with it the launcher appears with an error message which I can't remember exactly but it ran along the lines of: "Cannot run in sudo mode, please do it again in user mode." Funny Catch-22 if you ask me. I ended up uninstalling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: set the permissions of rclone.conf to `chmod 777`. I changed the whole folder and its files using `sudo chmod -R 777 /home/myUser/.config/rclone/` for good measure. Now I can finally retry installing Anaconda.